# What is this effect and how it can be implemented?

Tags: javascript, frontend, effects

Today I ran across [this website (of a book)](http://masteringmetrics.com) and discovered interesting visual effect (I guess, I would call it *changing virtual perspective* or similar). I'm curious about the term that this effect is properly referred to as well as about what front-end (JavaScript, I assume) frameworks, libraries, tools and/or languages can be used for implementing this and similar effects.

Comment: Yes that would be a parallax

Comment: @axelduch: Perhaps. Please see the link I initially forgot to include.

Comment: @axelduch: I see - thank you. I've heard the term, but wasn't sure that it applies to this case. So, what tools could be used to implement this effect? P.S. Wow! -1? Whoever downvoted: do you care to explain your reasoning?

Comment: To moderators: my question didn't imply a request for a fully comprehensive answer, so I see no point in labeling it as too broad and placing on hold. But, if you insist on this, I don't mind...

Answer (score 3):

It's an effect called Parallax. It's often used on scrolling websites, to give the illusion of depth.

This idea first came about with early computer games, to give 2D graphics a sense of movement, perception of speed and distance.

If you're after JavaScript libraries, there are many, but one popular one is: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Whilst many websites using Parallax attach the effect to the scroll event, the example website you gave attaches the event to the users mouse X and Y coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your detailed answer (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [parallax.js](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) might be a good place to start.  If you want to code it yourself, you could do something like use a couple of SVG layers and then use a transform to move some of the layers based on capturing the X and Y co-ordinates of mouseover events to calculate mouse movement.

For something slightly simpler (i.e. you don't want to learn SVG for a simple moving image), I guess you could use some images with [position: absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) and update their top & left properties based on the mouse location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1).

Comment: Edited to specify SVG as one option and include another.